# Declare DateTime in XAML in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I succesfully created some constants in Silverlight's XAML like that

```
  <sys:Boolean x:Key="foo">True</sys:Boolean>
```

However, when I try to do the same with a `DateTime` (to initialize some `DatePicker` 
controls)

```
<sys:DateTime x:Name="myDate"/>
```

the system throws an `XamlParseException` "Unknown element: DateTime. [Line: xxx Position: xxx]"

Is there a way to declare `DateTime` constants (I'm thinking of `DateTime.Now`) in XAML?

Answer (score 1):

In WPF you can do this with x:Static:

```
<FrameworkElement x:Key="dt" Tag="{x:Static s:DateTime.Now}" />
```

That's from Charles Petzold's all Xaml clock:
http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2006/04/070132.html

Unfortunately there is no Static markup attribute in Silverlight so I'm not sure how you'd replicate this.  Would really like to see an answer though!

Comment: cool. I was exploring that option but didn't think it would work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any way to do it without writing code. You'll have to expose `DateTime.Now` as a property in your data model, and bind to it as usual.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 Possible ways to do this:

**1:** (I didn't know you could do this until just now):

```
<x:Code>
    <![CDATA[
    private DateTime m_MyDateTime = DateTime.Now;
    ]]>
</x:Code>
```

**2.** You might try creating a CustomControl that inherits from FrameworkElement, and expose a DateTime DependencyProperty so you can DataBind to it.

**EDIT:**

I'm not 100% sure if either approach would work in Silverlight, I'm just offering a solution based on my experience with WPF Client Apps.